# Python: "No virtualenv active"

Tags: python, warnings, pycharm

I installed PyCharm 2.7 under Windows 8.1. It works fine, but every time I run a program, I get the following warning:

> WARNING:root:No virtualenv active

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: There is no need to post my code. I get this warning even when I run "print 32".

Answer (score 1):

Program you run needs a virtual environment to run. This is a nice python feature that allows you to isolate a python program within the scope of the specific python set of libraries it may need. If you do not run more than one Python program you may not be really worried about it. However, it you do, I would recommend to ready about virtualenv first.

ps. Also, it might be just a debug log for developers to make sure they switched virtual env.

Comment: I installed virtualenv, restarted PyCharm and I still got the warining. When I tried to reinstall it, I got the warning that "No virtualenv active", then a message that  "requirement  already satisfied" and the path to virtualenv. I am confused - it lookes like I installed it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to create a virtual env also too. However, I wouldn't be worried in your case. Here you can find a guide to proceed further: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Google helps a lot.